# Explanation of exporting a path variable

Tags: environment-variables, paths

Was hoping someone can explain what the command to exporting a path variable means?

e.g.:

```
alias TEST1="/usr/local/test1"

export PATH=$TEST1:$PATH
```

Does the colon append?

Comment: Your syntax is not correct, you don't need the `alias` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

$PATH is a variable where bash looks for executables.

It is a list of directories separated by a `:`

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

So yes you are adding $TEST1 to your path

If you set a variable in a bash shell, the variable is available only within the context of the script. When you export it, it is available outside the script.

See:

http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/030.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-bash/index.html